# Dojo request.post send empty body

Tags: php, ajax, post, dojo

I'm under Dojo 1.10

I want to post some data to php with request.post(). The request is sent but the POST body is empty.
Data is a JSON string here.
The request is NOT cross-domain.

I always wondered how Dojo handle keys in the query string, no information about these keys can be found in documentation except for "query" but it is not read in post requests.

```
sendPostRequest : function(url, data, sync)
        {
            var options = 
            {
                data : data,
                sync : sync,
                handleAs : "json"
            };


            return request.post(url, options)
            .then(function(response){
                _content = response;
                return _content;
            },
            function (error)
            {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

Dumped $_POST variable :

```
array(size=0) empty
```